# how to fetch file informations and md5 checksum using 1 command in linux

Tags: linux

I want to fetch all the file information viz: `"permission","hardlink","owner","group","fsize","month","date","time","filename"`

and

MD5 Sum information in one line command. How can I do this?

currently I get the 1st one by running `ls -latr /home/asimon`
and 2nd 1 by `md5sum /home/asimon/filename.sh` (it fetches me info for only 1 file) but instead i want all the information  like below

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 asimon support   4096 Sep 27 11:59 lib de1d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf842qw
-rwxrwxrwx  1 asimon support    924 Sep 27 12:00 run.sh dqtd8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf84a7a
drwxr-xr-x  6 asimon support   4096 Sep 27 18:13 plugins d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427s
-rw-r--r--  1 asimon support   2572 Sep 28 10:06 servicesFramework.log d51d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks rather clumsy, but here you go:
`ls -lAtr /home/asimon |grep -v total|awk '{printf($ARGV[1]);printf(" ");system("md5sum $9");}'|tr -d "-"`

[EDIT]
note the upper case `A` in the ls command

[EDIT2 and 3]
Upated command, not spoiling the '-' characters in file names:

`ls -lAtr /home/asimon|egrep -v "^d|total"|awk '{printf($ARGV[1]);printf(" ");system("md5sum $9");}'|awk '{$11="";print $ARGV[1]}'`

Comment: This works :) so if i need to give a path so your one liner may change something like this `ls -lAtr /home/asimon|grep -v total|awk '{printf($ARGV[1]);printf(" ");system("md5sum $9");}'|tr -d "-"`?

Comment: yes, but take a look at the updated command

Answer (score 7):

you can do it with find very easily:

```
find . -printf "%m %n %u %g %s  %t" -exec md5sum \{\} \;
```

Instead of the printf and the options you could also do a `-ls` but that would print the file name twice (and the ouput from md5sum delimited with a newline char)

Comment: nice one, it does not print the data in the right order though, and does include ".

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways would be to use a `for` loop as follows:

```
for ls_entry in `ls`;do [ -f $ls_entry ] && ls_out=`ls -alth $ls_entry` && md5_out=`md5sum $ls_entry|awk '{print $1}'` && echo "$ls_out $md5_out"; done
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

try: ls -latr /home/asimon; md5sum /home/asimon/*

the semicolon lets you do two commands on one line, and the * will run md5sum for everything in that directory.

Comment: I need information in one line `drwxr-xr-x  2 asimon support   4096 Sep 27 11:59 lib de1d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf842qw`